# Docker on Elastic Beanstalk - connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds

I am trying to run a simple Sign Up Flask app on AWS Elastic Beanstalk (this app: https://github.com/jay3dec/PythonFlaskMySQLApp---Part-1 ) connected to an external MySQL database, hosted on AWS RDS.

The app runs perfectly locally (even when I connect to the AWS RDS from my local app).

But when I do eb open in the command line, I get:

```
502 Bad Gateway

nginx/1.8.1
```

When I did eb create, I received the warning:

```
WARN    Only one EXPOSE directive is allowed, using the first one: 3306
```

because in my Dockerfile, I had:

```
EXPOSE 3306
EXPOSE 5000
```

For eb logs, I have:

```
/var/log/nginx/error.log
-------------------------------------
2016/07/17 15:18:06 [warn] 8928#0: duplicate MIME type "text/html" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/elasticbeanstalk-nginx-docker-proxy.conf:11
2016/07/17 15:18:06 [warn] 8934#0: duplicate MIME type "text/html" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/elasticbeanstalk-nginx-docker-proxy.conf:11
2016/07/17 15:20:54 [error] 8937#0: *33 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.6.93, server: , request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.17.0.2:3306/favicon.ico", host: "flasksecgroup-dev.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com", referrer: "http://flasksecgroup-dev.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/"
```

My Dockerfile is:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y python-pip libmysqlclient-dev python-dev build-    essential
 COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Expose
EXPOSE 3306
EXPOSE 5000

ENTRYPOINT ["python"]
CMD ["app.py"]
```

Comment: Is you port 3306 open to world in your security group.

Comment: I opened all ports and this error disappeared, thanks.

Comment: I have answered the question. Please mark it as correct if it worked for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a port and security firewall issue. Open port 3306 and 5000 to world in your security group. It will work without any error.

Answer (score -3):

If you can add your Dockerfile to the repository, i can check it

Comment: This is not a answer.

Comment: i added dockerfile in the question

Comment: pls add also requirements.txt to the github repo

Comment: my requirements.txt:   Flask==0.10.1
Flask-MySQL==1.3
Flask-WTF==0.12
MySQL-python==1.2.5
oauthlib==0.6.1

websocket-client==0.37.0
Werkzeug==0.10.4
WTForms==2.1

Comment: pls push this file to the repository, copy paste has potential risks to test.